Do Azure OpenAI o1 GPT model support image analysis like GPT Vision?
I'm exploring Azure OpenAI and noticed some interesting reasoning capabilities mentioned in the documentation. I wanted to know if the o1 GPT model support image analysis similar to GPT Vision.
For example, could I use something like this to analyze an image?
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-4o-mini",
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": [
                {"type": "text", "text": "What's in this image?"},
                {
                    "type": "image_url",
                    "image_url": {
                        "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Gfp-wisconsin-madison-the-nature-boardwalk.jpg/2560px-Gfp-wisconsin-madison-the-nature-boardwalk.jpg",
                    },
                },
            ],
        }
    ],
    max_tokens=300,
)

print(response.choices[0])

Does Azure OpenAI o1 model currently have this capability?

Yes. I know some people who are using GPT 4o to do this. I believe you can either provide the image URL as a reference like in your example, or as base64 data.

there are 2 parts to your question.

the link you provided is more about [Azure OpenAI reasoning models], especially the 'Azure OpenAI o1 and o1-mini models'. these two models are currently still in preview, you will not be able to use it until you fill in the request access form. https://aka.ms/oai/modelaccess



your code and question seems to more related to using a GPT model with vision support so that you can attach an image and ask questions about the image. for this, you can use the gpt-4o model (or any model with vision support) in Azure OpenAI service, GPT-4o is currently public (dont need additional request form).

